# Totals from a multidimensional array in PASCAL

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization, pascal

I have a program where I take user input info about products made in a factory and split the information into 2 tables. The first table is for good products and the second is for bad. Each table represents how many of each product (10 products) are made by each machine (7 machines). There are supposed to be totals on the Y-axis (for total products made per machine) and X-axis (for total of a specific product across all machines)

I have a total on the Y-axis, but it always comes out wrong. It shows 10 by default instead of 0 and when you add one to it, it becomes 9 instead of 1.

Here is the code:

```
program Production8;

uses crt;

var
  machine: array of char;
  machineindex: integer;
  product: array of integer;
  quality: array of integer;
  min, number: integer;
  i, j, k, extra, total: integer;
  myTable: array[0..6,0..9,0..1] of integer;


procedure Header;

begin
  writeln('Production Overview');
  writeln();
end;
procedure Quit;

begin
  writeln();
  writeln('To Quit hit <ENTER>');
  readln;
end;

procedure ShowTable(pQuality: integer; pTitle: string);

begin
  writeln(pTitle);
  writeln('  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   T');
  for i := 0 to 6 do
    begin
     total := 0;
     write(CHR(65+i),' ');
     for j := 0 to 9 do
      begin
       write(myTable[i,j,pQuality], '   ');
       if myTable[machineindex,(product[number]),(quality[number])]
       = myTable[i,j,pQuality] then
         begin
          total:= total + 1;
         end;
       if j = 9 then
        begin
         write (total);
        end;
       end;
      writeln('');
     end;
  writeln ('T');
end;

begin
  for i:= 0 to 6 do
     for j:= 0 to 9 do
      for k:= 0 to 1 do
        myTable[i, j, k]:= 0;
  i:= 0;
  j:= 0;
  number := 0;
  min := 1;
  extra := 1;
  SETLENGTH( machine, min );
  SETLENGTH( product, min );
  SETLENGTH( quality, min );
  Header;
  writeln('Input Machine ID ( A, B, C, D, E, F or G ). Input "*" to stop');
  readln(machine[number] );
  while (machine[number] <> '*') do
  begin
    while ( ORD( machine[number] ) < 65 ) or ( ORD( machine[number] ) > 71 ) do
    begin
      writeln('Input Invalid. Please try again.');
      readln(machine[number] );
    end;
    clrscr;
    Header;
    machineindex := (ORD(machine[number])-65);
    writeln('Input Product Number ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9 ) ');
    readln(product[number] );
    while ( product[number] < 0 ) or ( product[number] > 9 ) do
    begin
      writeln('Input Invalid. Please try again.');
      readln(product[number] );
    end;
    clrscr;
    Header;
    writeln('Quality Control Check. Input 0 for GOOD or 1 for BAD.');
    readln(quality[number] );
    while ( quality[number] <> 0 ) and ( quality[number] <> 1 ) do
    begin
      writeln('Input Invalid. Please try again.');
      readln(quality[number] );
    end;
    clrscr;
    Header;
    myTable[machineindex,(product[number]),(quality[number])] :=
    myTable[machineindex,(product[number]),(quality[number])] + 1;
    number := number + 1;
    if number = LENGTH(machine) then
    begin
      SETLENGTH(machine, LENGTH(machine)+extra);
      SETLENGTH(product, LENGTH(product)+extra);
      SETLENGTH(quality, LENGTH(quality)+extra)
    end;
    writeln('Input Machine ID ( A, B, C, D, E, F or G ). Input "*" to stop');
    readln(machine[number] );
  end;
  clrscr;
  Header;
  ShowTable(0, 'Good Products');

  writeln();
  ShowTable(1, 'Bad Products');
  Quit;
end.
```

At first I thought the problem was with my initialisation, as I didn't have "myTable" initialised. Now I do and the problem persists. Where am I going wrong?

Also, I'm not sure how to achieve a total on the X-axis. How can I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the summation of the var "total" is not correct.

I tried to make the code work without making to many design changes to your code:

```
procedure ShowTable(pQuality: integer; pTitle: string);
var totalx: integer;
    totaly: array[0..9] of integer;
begin
  // initialize array totaly
  for j:= 0 to 9 do 
    totaly[j] := 0;

  // output header
  writeln(pTitle);
  writeln('  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   T');

  // iterate machines
  for i := 0 to 6 do
  begin
    totalx := 0;
    write(CHR(65+i),' ');

    for j := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      write(myTable[i,j,pQuality], '   ');

      if myTable[i,j,pQuality] = 1 then
      begin
        totalx:= totalx + 1;
        totaly[j] := totaly[j] + 1;
      end;

      if j = 9 then
      begin
        write (totalx);
      end;
    end;

    writeln('');
  end;

  write('T ');
  total := 0;

  for j := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    total := total + totaly[j];
    write(totaly[j], '   ');
  end;
  write(total);
```

end;

Generally try to reduce your use of global variables and use more comments.
You should also consider object oriented concepts...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You've made the code so much better and easier to understand.

Comment: I should let you know I found a small problem in the code but I was able to fix it, I think.

When you put:
      if myTable[i,j,pQuality] = 1 then
      begin
        totalx:= totalx + 1;
        totaly[j] := totaly[j] + 1;
      end; 
this resulted in the total only adding if there were no more than 1 in each cell of the table.
   I changed it to this:

if myTable[i,j,pQuality] > 0 then
      begin
        totalx:= totalx + myTable[i, j, pQuality];
        totaly[j] := totaly[j] + myTable[i, j, pQuality];
      end;  

And now it works fine, I think.
Is thr no way to make this more readable?

Comment: That last bit is not a question about the code btw. It's in reference to the comments on this site and how hard it is to put code in them :D